# VM5601:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to get data with ajax and jquery. But i get thhis error and i dont know how to fix it.

> VM5601:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 10

This is my code.

Model

```
public function GetBloodCatById($id)
{
    $this->db->from('tbl_blood_cat');
    $this->db->where('id_blood_cat',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row();
}
```

Controller

```
public function ajax_edit($id)
{
        $data = $this->Blood->GetBloodCatById($id);
        echo json_encode($data);
}
```

View

```
function edit_blood(id)
  {
    save_method = 'update';
    $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals

    //Ajax Load data from ajax
    $.ajax({ 

      url : "<?php echo site_url('Home/ajax_edit/')?>/" + id,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "JSON",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(data)
      {
          $('[name="id_blood_cat"]').val(data.id_blood_cat);
          $('[name="catName"]').val(data.category);   

          $('#myModalBloodCat').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
          $('.modal-title').text('Edit Blood Cat'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
      {
        alert(errorThrown);
      }
  });
  }
```

This is data that will be get

```
{"id_blood_cat":"1","category":"Plasma","createBy":"nicky","updateBy":null,"createAt":"2017-05-11 18:30:09","updateAt":"2017-05-11 18:30:09","flag":"1"}
```

I had been strugle with this for hours. Please help me thx.

Comment: Try putting an `exit;` after `echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: check the data return from controller

Comment: nothing change @gaganshera

Comment: the data that i post above is the result from my controler's return data @SamirNabil

Comment: look I was face this problem with angular, I make my return like this and work try it `echo '[{"result":"no"}]';`

Comment: where should i put that code? @SamirNabil

Comment: change `echo json_encode($data);` to `echo '['. json_encode($data) . ']';`

Comment: it's not working @SamirNabil, stilll get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144721/discussion-between-samir-nabil-and-nicky-apriliani).

Answer (score 0):

Reomve php tag  and try to set url like this

```
 url : "/Home/ajax_edit/?id=" + id,
```

Comment: error 404 not found because it will only go to my localhost not my project folder

Comment: Is your controller and action method is same like this url

Comment: Yups it is sam @Jay

Answer (score 0):

wrapping json in array is always good choice.Here i have modified your function little

```
public function ajax_edit($id)
{       $res = array(); 
        $data = $this->Blood->GetBloodCatById($id);
        $res = $data;
        echo json_encode($data);
}
```

and ajax success handler is like

```
........
success: function(data)
      {   response = $.parseJSON(data);
          $.each(data, function (i, item) {
          $('[name="id_blood_cat"]').val(response.id_blood_cat);
          $('[name="catName"]').val(response.category);   
         }
        $('#myModalBloodCat').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
          $('.modal-title').text('Edit Blood Cat'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

      },
........
```

Comment: what is your ajax response ,it should be like [{"Id":10,"ContactId":4554,"ExpirationMonth":"02","ExpirationYear":"2018"}]

Comment: {"id_blood_cat":"1","category":"Plasma","createBy":"nicky","updateBy":null,"createAt":"2017-05-11 18:30:09","updateAt":"2017-05-11 18:30:09","flag":"1"}

Answer (score 0):

Try: `url: 'file:///Home/ajax_edit/?id='+id`

Comment: i got this error
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Home/ajax_edit/?id=1. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: try adding another key to the object being passed to the `$.ajax` method : `dataType: "jsonp",` let me know if this works. Otherwise try serving the path `Home/ajax_edit/` on a localhost and then change the url to `url: http://localhost:<portNumber>/`

Comment: this is what i get

Comment: jquery.min.js:4 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///Home/ajax_edit/?id=1&callback=jQuery2240693571617935312_1495276586471&_=1495276586472

Comment: Go into the `Home` directory, then set up a localhost by doing `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` then type in the url `'http://localhost:8000/ajax_edit/?id='+id`

Comment: where is home directory? can u tell me more about it?

Comment: I'm using loocalhost, how can i access home directory?